# OpenSSL problems with Apache and PHP 7, how do I fix it/what went wrong?

Tags: php, apache, openssl

Whenever I try to start apache, I get this error message :

```
Cannot load modules/libphp7.so into server: /usr/local/apache/modules/libphp7.so: undefined symbol: SSL_get0_alpn_selected
```

This is after compiling apache 2 with this configure :

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache --sysconfdir=/etc/apache --enable-so   --enable-rewrite  --enable-ssl
```

And PHP like this

```
sudo ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs --with-mysqli --with-bz2 --with-zlib --enable-zip --enable-mbstring --with-mcrypt --with-openssl
```

I've followed this tutorial : http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/install-apache2-ssl/

except i've replaced /usr/local/apache/conf with /etc/apache

Until i followed the tutorial, I got no error messages.

Comment: What is the OpenSSL 1.0.2f installation failure? You don't seem to provide the error message or details for it.

Comment: Sorry, might have phrased it wrong, what I meant was after install openssl, php7, mysql and apache 2.4.18 all from source, and following that tutorial, I got the first error message when starting apache.